# Rails API with ActionCable (WS) and React Front End

Tags: reactjs, forms, rails-api, actioncable

I have setup WebSockets through ActionCable for my Rails API/React Front End application and I am struggling with some real odd functionality.  Currently, my `<ActionCableConsumer />` is firing randomly.  Let's say I have four browsers open and I submit a form that should render new data to all four browsers, two may stream the data from the channel, while the other two render nothing.  Or one of the browsers may render the data more than once, while the other three render nothing.  It truly is a sporadic deal.

Here is where I take the data from the subscription and update the state:

```
    handleReceived = (message) => {
      console.log('check me')
      this.setState({
        apiData: [...this.state.apiData, message.pickup_delivery]
     });
    }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <ActionCableConsumer channel={{channel: 'PickupDeliveriesChannel'}} onReceived={this.handleReceived}>
        <div>
          <CustomersForm showCustForm={this.state.showCustForm} handleClose={this.hideForm} addNewCustomer={this.addNewCustomer} />
          <Calendar getCustForm={this.getCustForm} getForm={this.getForm} deleteLoad={this.deleteLoad} {...this.state} seededColorGenerator={this.seededColorGenerator} />
          <PickupDeliveriesForm getFormColor={this.getFormColor} deleteCustomer={this.deleteCustomer} handleClose={this.hideForm} showForm={this.state.showForm} updateLoad={this.updateLoad} {...this.state} onNewLoad={this.addNewLoad} seededColorGenerator={this.seededColorGenerator} />
        </div>
      </ActionCableConsumer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is what my controller looks like:

```
module Api::V1
  class PickupDeliveriesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_pickup_delivery, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /pickup_deliveries
    def index
      @pickup_deliveries = PickupDelivery.all

      render json: @pickup_deliveries
    end

  # GET /pickup_deliveries/1
    def show
      render json: @pickup_delivery
    end

  # POST /pickup_deliveriesPickupDeliveries
    def create
    pickup_deliveries = PickupDelivery.new(pickup_delivery_params)
    if pickup_deliveries.save
      serialized_data = ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Json.new(
        PickupDeliveriesSerializer.new(pickup_deliveries)
      ).serializable_hash
      ActionCable.server.broadcast 'pickup_deliveries_channel', serialized_data
      head :ok
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pickup_deliveries/1
    def update
      if @pickup_delivery.update(pickup_delivery_params)
        render json: @pickup_delivery
      else
        render json: @pickup_delivery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

  # DELETE /pickup_deliveries/1
    def destroy
      @pickup_delivery.destroy
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_pickup_delivery
       @pickup_delivery = PickupDelivery.find(params[:id])
      end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
      def pickup_delivery_params
        params.require(:pickup_delivery).permit(:id, :pickup_date, :pickup_location, :rate, :delivery_date, :delivery_location, :local_delivery, :local_pickup, :loaded_miles, :deadhead_miles, :delivery_id, :pickup_zip, :delivery_zip, :hazmat, :sameday, :delivery_time, :pickup_time, :aurora_number, :out_of_route, :round_trip, :customer_id, :color)
      end
  end
end
```

Here is my actual channel:

```
class PickupDeliveriesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from 'pickup_deliveries_channel'
  end
end
```

I am not specifying any users because I don't need to yet.  Basically, when a client submits a new load on the load board, I need all the other load boards to display the new instance.  Currently, it is not working like that all.

With five browsers open and after one form submission on a random browser, three out of the five browsers rendered the correct data (one load), one browser rendered nothing and one browser rendered the data TWICE.

It is pure chaos lol.

```
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
PickupDeliveriesChannel transmitting {"pickup_delivery"=>{"id"=>17, "pickup_date"=>"2019-11-16", "pickup_location"=>"", "rate"=>nil, "delivery_date"=>"2019-11-16", "delivery_location"=>"", "local_delivery"=>false, "local_pickup"=>false, "loaded_miles"=>nil, "deadhead_miles"=>nil, "delivery_id"=>nil, "pickup_zip"=>"", "delivery_zip"=... (via streamed from pickup_deliveries_channel)
Unsubscribing from channel: {"channel":"PickupDeliveriesChannel"}
PickupDeliveriesChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
PickupDeliveriesChannel is streaming from pickup_deliveries_channel
PickupDeliveriesChannel stopped streaming from pickup_deliveries_channel
Unsubscribing from channel: {"channel":"PickupDeliveriesChannel"}
PickupDeliveriesChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
PickupDeliveriesChannel is streaming from pickup_deliveries_channel
PickupDeliveriesChannel stopped streaming from pickup_deliveries_channel
Unsubscribing from channel: {"channel":"PickupDeliveriesChannel"}
Unsubscribing from channel: {"channel":"PickupDeliveriesChannel"}
PickupDeliveriesChannel stopped streaming from pickup_deliveries_channel
PickupDeliveriesChannel stopped streaming from pickup_deliveries_channel
Unsubscribing from channel: {"channel":"PickupDeliveriesChannel"}
Could not execute command from ({"command"=>"unsubscribe", "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"PickupDeliveriesChannel\"}"}) [RuntimeError - Unable to find subscription with identifier: {"channel":"PickupDeliveriesChannel"}]: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.3/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:78:in `find' | C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.3/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:46:in `remove' | C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.3/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:18:in `execute_command' | C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.3/lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb:87:in `dispatch_websocket_message' | C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.3/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
PickupDeliveriesChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
PickupDeliveriesChannel is streaming from pickup_deliveries_channel
Unsubscribing from channel: {"channel":"PickupDeliveriesChannel"}
PickupDeliveriesChannel stopped streaming from pickup_deliveries_channel
PickupDeliveriesChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
PickupDeliveriesChannel is streaming from pickup_deliveries_channel
```

On that specific submission, here is what my rails console looks like.

It is pure chaos and I have no idea how to make it flow correctly.

EDIT:
The more form submissions I go through, the more subscriptions are being opened.  It's almost like every time I open the form to submit something, another subscription is streaming?  With two browsers open, I can be transmitting any number of objects...

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :pickup_deliveries
        resources :customers
        end
    end
    mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
end
```

Here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { ActionCableProvider } from 'react-actioncable-provider';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { API_WS_ROOT } from './constants';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ActionCableProvider url={API_WS_ROOT}>
    <App />
  </ActionCableProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Here are the constants that I am using

```
export const API_ROOT = 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1';
export const API_WS_ROOT = 'ws://localhost:3001/cable';
export const HEADERS = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Accept: 'application/json',
};
```

Comment: Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: Yup, I did.  I sent the current state that contained all my fetched instances VIA ````params```` to the channel and compared it with the current database.  To be honest, I am not exactly sure as to why it worked.  Basically, I said if ````params[:all_loads]```` (current fetched response in the front end) is equal to the amount of instances in the back end object, then continue to stream to channel.  The solution is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out.  I sent the current state that contained all my fetched instances VIA `params` from the front end to the channel and compared it with the current database.  To be honest, I am not exactly sure as to why it worked.  Basically, I said if `params[:all_loads]` (current fetched response in the front end) is equal to the amount of instances in the back end object, then continue to stream to channel.  The solution is below:

```
class PickupDeliveriesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    if params[:all_loads].length == PickupDelivery.all.length
        stream_from 'pickup_deliveries_channel'
    end
  end

  def unsubscribed

  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

websocket supports one connection per app instance, there is one server an one client. the update is not random, it goes to the last app had the connection open with the websocket.

Comment: So if I use this implementation on a network of computers, will I get the desired result?  I literally just dove into Web Sockets last night, so forgive me for my ignorance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API , read more about the API here. What i think is your problem, is that the connection of  the socket and the app is being interrupted , so your apps lose the communication. You should try  keeping the connection alive sending ping/pong messages between server and client after an interval

Comment: that is exactly what is happening... I will look at this!  Thank you!  EDIT:  Do you have a good starting point on how to do this?

Comment: docs are great, you should check them for sure. they have guides on how to implement both server and client. you can start by sending a ping message fron server to client after the handshake and setup the client so that responds with a pong message whenever receives ping messages from the server. Repeating the ping/pong messaging after a time interval will weep websocket communication alive.

Comment: By the way, this is from the ActionCable documentation "A single Action Cable server can handle multiple connection instances. It has one connection instance per WebSocket connection. A single user may have multiple WebSockets open to your application if they use multiple browser tabs or devices. The client of a WebSocket connection is called the consumer."  Looks like I should be able to utilize multiple browsers.

Comment: And the most frustrating part is, multiple browsers in development CAN work as intended.  There are times where both browsers update and render perfectly, so I do know it's possible.  I just can't decide if it's a client or server issue.